# Measuring effectiveness of qdisc

Tags: networking, tc, iperf, htb

I am trying to set the incoming and outgoing bandwidth of a particular interface. I set the outgoing bandwidth in the following way.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev f30e888e9a857_c handle 1: root htb default 11
sudo tc class add dev f30e888e9a857_c parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100kbit ceil 100kbit
sudo tc class add dev f30e888e9a857_c parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 100kbit ceil 100kbit
```

To confirm that this throttling worked, I used iperf3 (just using iperf3 -c ip_address) between two nodes. Throttling occurs but the bandwidth I am seeing is 8.5Mb/sec (8510 Kb/sec), which is 80x the bandwidth I've throttled the interface to. Could someone explain this discrepency?

Also, is there a way to set the incoming bandwidth on the same interface?

Comment: You are shaping the upload traffic. Is the bandwidth you look at the upload or download one? What is the upload bandwidth?